# protoc file for grpc helloworld is same for 64-bit and 32-bit. if not can you please post the 32-bit protoc file for helloworld

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc, 32-bit

I have build the lib in 32-bit on cmake(3.17.1-win64-x64.msi). unable to compile hello world.

```
error:
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:103 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package "Protobuf" that is
compatible with requested version "".

The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

C:/grpc/.build/build32/third_party/protobuf/cmake/protobuf-config.cmake, version: 3.11.2.0 (32bit)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: I am no CMake expert, but I have a strong guess that the various output logs it mentions may have hints on what went wrong.  It might also help to post your cmake file for others to see.

Comment: seems to me like, `protobuf` doesn't fit with the `cmake` version. Please check any README and/or disclaimer etc. in `protobuf`, either there is some version dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This error has actually nothing to do with the protoc file. It is a CMake error that basically says: *"Hey, I've found a protobuf installation at **X** but this is only compiled as a 32-bit library. Your current compiler, however, is a 64-bit compiler, so I can't use this library."*

I suspect you used some different settings when compiling gRPC/protobuf compared to your current settings when compiling your own project. You have the same compiler and the same build architecture for both compiling gRPC/protobuf *and* your own project.

I don't know your current compiler settings but I'd say if you instruct CMake to use a 32-bit compiler instead of a (auto-detected) 64-bit one, you should be good to go.